# Get the command that Visual Studio uses to build the container

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, containers, visual-studio-2019

I did a basic Web API .NET Core project in Visual Studio 2019.  I selected to run in a Linux Container.

When you build and run, it creates the container from the docker file that is created.

I would like to see the command it uses to create the container.  I know it will be something like this:

```
docker image build --tag mysolution:dev --file .\Dockerfile .
```

But I would like to see what the actual command is.

I tried looking through the build output and the Container Tools output, but I could not find this command logged in there anywhere.

**Is there a way to see what command is used to build the container?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to record and explore what arguments were used to start a process.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "**MSBuild project build output verbosity**" set to at least Minimal (Under Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run), then you should be able to see all the Docker commands that Visual Studio executes in the output window.

It would be in "Container Tools" or "Build" output window.